# Strictly typing React higher order component which consumes properties with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, higher-order-components

I'm trying to type some higher order React components which are more complex than only injecting properties. These HOCs must be able to:

- receive properties that are not (or only optionally) forwarded to the wrapped component
- provide some new properties to the wrapped component
- take additional arguments when they are created

From what I can tell, this means we must have three types:

1. The properties the HOC provides to the wrapped component
2. The properties the HOC uses, but which the wrapped component not necessarily cares about
3. The properties of the wrapped component that the HOC doesn't care about

I have the following code that works, but I can't find a way to avoid the `any` cast when passing the props on to the wrapped component:

```js
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';

// Props of the wrapped component without the props provided by the HOC
type StrictWrappedProps<WrappedProps, InjectedProps> = Omit<
  WrappedProps,
  keyof InjectedProps
>;

type WrappedComponent<WrappedProps, InjectedProps> = ComponentType<
  WrappedProps & InjectedProps
>;

type HOCType<WrappedProps, InjectedProps, OwnProps> = ComponentType<
  OwnProps & StrictWrappedProps<WrappedProps, InjectedProps>
>;

type LengthifyOwnProps = {
  name: string;
};

type LengthifyInjectedProps = {
  length: number;
};

export const lengthify = <WrappedProps extends {}>(
  Wrapped: WrappedComponent<WrappedProps, LengthifyInjectedProps>,
  multiplier: number
): HOCType<WrappedProps, LengthifyInjectedProps, LengthifyOwnProps> => ({
  name,
  ...props
}) => {
  const length = name.length * multiplier;
  return <Wrapped {...props as any} length={length} />;
};
```

Here is an example usage of that HOC:

```js
const myComp = ({ bool, length }: { bool: boolean; length: number }) => (
  <p>
    Bool is: {bool}. Length is: {length}
  </p>
);

const EnhancedMyComp = lengthify(myComp, 2);

const usage = () => <EnhancedMyComp bool={true} name="Hello" />;
```

The `any` cast is a small workaround, but I would like to find the strict way of typing this.

The [React TypeScript cheat sheet on HOCs](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet/blob/master/HOC.md) links to [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28938#issuecomment-548170405) in the TypeScript repo, but it seems to be more or less solved, and only relates to HOCs that inject properties.
Other questions here on StackOverflow also seem to to be about injecting properties, or confusion about the `ComponentType` type.

Comment: I would keep the `as` assertion but define like this: https://tsplay.dev/rNdPkN